# How is Google Cloud Pub/Sub avoiding clock skew

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking into ways to order list of messages from google cloud pub/sub. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) says:

> Have a way to determine from all messages it has currently received whether or not there are messages it has not yet received that it needs to process first.
>
> ...is possible by using Cloud Monitoring to keep track of the `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/oldest_unacked_message_age` metric. A subscriber would temporarily put all messages in some persistent storage and ack the messages. It would periodically check the oldest unacked message age and check against the publish timestamps of the messages in storage. All messages published before the oldest unacked message are guaranteed to have been received, so those messages can be removed from persistent storage and processed in order.

I tested it locally and this approach seems to be working fine.

I have one gripe with it however, and this is not something easily testable by myself.

This solution relies on server-side assigned (by google) `publish_time` attribute. How does Google avoid the issues of skewed clocks?

If my producer publishes messages A and then immediately B, how can I be sure that `A.publish_time < B.publish_time` is true? Especially considering that the same documentation page mentions internal load-balancers in the architecture of the solution. Is Google Pub/Sub using atomic clocks to synchronize time on the very first machines which see messages and enrich those messages with the current time?

There is an implicit assumption in the recommended solution that the clocks on all the servers are synchronized. But the documentation never explains if that is true or how it is achieved so I feel a bit uneasy about the solution. Does it work under very high load?

Notice I am only interested in relative order of confirmed messages published after each other. If two messages are published simultaneously, I don't care about the order of them between each other. It can be `A, B` or `B, A`. I only want to make sure that if B is published after A is published, then I can sort them in that order on retrieval.

Is the aforementioned solution only "best-effort" or are there actual guarantees about this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sides to ordered message delivery: establishing an order of messages on the publish side and having an established order of processing messages on the subscribe side. The document to which you refer is mostly concerned with the latter, particularly when it comes to using `oldest_unacked_message_age`. When using this method, one can know that if message A has a publish timestamp that is less than the publish timestamp for message B, then a subscriber will always process message A before processing message B. Essentially, once the order is established (via publish timestamps), it will be consistent. This works if it is okay for the Cloud Pub/Sub service itself to establish the ordering of messages.

Publish timestamps are not synchronized across servers and so if it is necessary for the order to be established by the publishers, it will be necessary for the publishers to provide a timestamp (or sequence number) as an attribute that is used for ordering in the subscriber (and synchronized across publishers). The subscriber would sort message by this user-provided timestamp instead of by the publish timestamp. The `oldest_unacked_message_age` will no longer be exact because it is tied to the publish timestamp. One could be more conservative and only consider messages ordered that are older than `oldest_unacked_message_age` minus some delta to account for this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Pub-sub does not guarantee order of events receive to consumers as they were produced. Reason behind that is Google Cloud Pub-sub also running on a cluster of nodes. The possibility is there an event B can reach the consumer before event A. To Ensure ordering you have to make changes on both producer and consumer to identify the order of events. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) is section from docs.